# Prime number detector between 0 and 101, digital logic karnaugh map

Tags: vhdl, primes, karnaugh-map

For the input of 101, one needs to have 7 bits, but I dunno how to start drawing a k-map with 7 variables...

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlxMev7l3ac) a tutorial on doing 5 variable k-map, and the SOP equation is:

F = a' b' e + a' b' c' d + b c d' e + a c d e + b' c' e + a' c' d e

Which I guess can be used in VHDL, you input some number, and F will output 1 if the number is prime (e.g. 7) or 0 if it's not. But this equation only supports number up to 31, how do I find an equation that'll cover prime numbers between 0 and 101??

How would I start doing the k-map? Would my a input also be separate kind of like the in the youtube example?

Comment: Note that Wikipedia tells us 1 isn't generally considered a [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) in the last century and a half or so. Not doing so produces 8 terms instead of the 6 shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps:

1. Make truth table for 0 to 101, in which `F` should be 1 for prime number.
2. Insert that truth table [here](http://www.32x8.com/var7.html).
3. Obtain reduced boolean equation and Rock!!

For more than six variable, It is too much tedious to handle K-Map Squares as it is too much. You can use **Tabulation Method** (***Quine-McCluskey***). See [link](http://www.electronicsengineering.nbcafe.in/quine-mccluskey-tabulation-method/).

Comment: that's doing with truth table, but how does one do it with a k-map? would I have "abc defg" variables, right? Would abc be on the horizontal lines, and "defg" on the vertical?

Comment: The red lines delineate the two 4 element Karnaugh maps for the 5 variable version (it duplicates the work shown in the video), or the eight 4 element Karnaugh maps for the 7 variable problem. The web page should do splendidly for learning to organize larger variables into 4 element K maps.

Comment: What? can't you just show how a k-map table will look like with 7 variables?

Comment: @Jack: K-map for 7 variables is **not really doable by hand**. You can certainly draw a K-map for 2^7 = 128 truth-table's rows, but you would not easily see, which cells are neighbouring. That is why you should use the Quine-McCluskey method, where you can compute/find the difference between each of the combinations of the 7 variables. Maybe there is another way dealing with the problem, but I would not recommend drawing a K-map.